# How to select the rows by range?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have following table named 'T'

[image]

**My desired output should be as following,**

[image]

I want to select those rows where column **'Actual'** should have range between column **'Basic'**, however if you take example for **'Model'** = HT65
**'Actual'** = 23.2 which has range between 22 & 24 of column **'Basic'** so I should get row as following where column **'Level'** is 2

[image]

Likewise other rows should be selected.
your help would be appreciated.

Comment: what did you tired so far?

Comment: I have no idea what your question is about.  You might want to explain the logic a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using multiple `LEFT JOIN` to join the next and last row of the current row. With some additional conditions you can check for the range:

```
SELECT t1.Model, t1.Level, t1.Basic, t1.Actual
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Model ORDER BY Basic) AS rn 
  FROM test
) t1 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Model ORDER BY Basic) AS rn 
  FROM test
) t2 ON t1.Model = t2.Model AND t1.rn + 1 = t2.rn LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Model ORDER BY Basic) AS rn 
  FROM test
) t3 ON t1.Model = t3.Model AND t1.rn - 1 = t3.rn
WHERE (t1.Actual BETWEEN t3.Basic AND t1.Basic)
  OR (t3.Model IS NULL AND t1.Actual < t1.Basic)
  OR (t2.Model IS NULL AND t1.Actual > t1.Basic)
ORDER BY t1.Model ASC
```

The above query gets all expected rows. I also added some additional cases to improve the query for these (special) cases. The above solution is working with SQL-Server 2008.

---

Since SQL-Server 2012 you can use the following solution using [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) and [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql):

```
SELECT t.Model, t.Level, t.Basic, t.Actual
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(Basic, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY Model ORDER BY Basic) AS prevBasic,
    LEAD(Basic, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Model ORDER BY Basic) AS nextBasic
  FROM test 
) t 
WHERE (t.Actual BETWEEN t.prevBasic AND t.Basic)
   OR (t.nextBasic = 0 AND t.Actual > t.Basic)
ORDER BY t.Model ASC
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=568669e6b5c771e7c801acc2e9b25394)